# Spring boot webflux how to save update and delete multiple Monos at the same time

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-cassandra

I have searched and i haven't gotten any concrete answers on this. Am using Cassandra as my database and i have three tables with the same attributes. How can i save, update and delete the same data on these three tables at the same time.

user table

```
Create Table user (
  userid bigint,
  username text,
  password text,
  name text,
  email text,
  phone text,
  birthday text,
  biography text,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)
```

user_username table

```
Create Table user (
  username text,
  userid bigint,
  password text,
  name text,
  email text,
  phone text,
  birthday text,
  biography text,
  PRIMARY KEY (username)
)
```

user_email table

```
Create Table user (
  email text,
  username text,
  userid bigint,
  password text,
  name text,
  phone text,
  birthday text,
  biography text,
  PRIMARY KEY (email)
```

)

These are the repositories

```
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<User, Long> {
}

public interface UserUsernameRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<UserUsername, String> {
}

public interface UserEmailRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<UserEmail, String> {
}
```

I can save them individually but not at the same time

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createUser(ServerRequest request) {
  Mono<User> user = request.bodyToMono(User.class);
  return ServerResponse.ok().build(userRepository.saveUser(user));
}
```

SignUp POJO (JSON Payload)

```
public class SignUp {
  private String name;
  private String username;
  private String email;
  private String password;
}

public Mono<ServerResponse> post(ServerRequest request) {
  Mono<SignUp> signUp = request.bodyToMono(SignUp.class);
  final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
  return created(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("user/" + id).build().toUri())
    .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(
        fromPublisher(
            signUp.map(u -> new User(u, id)).flatMap(userManager::saveUser), User.class)
            signUp.map(u -> new UserUsername(u, id)).flatMap(userManager::saveUsername), User.class)
            signUp.map(u -> new UserEmail(u, id)).flatMap(userManager::saveEmail), User.class)
            );
}

I need help to resolve this issues. The same thing goes to delete and update 

public Mono<ServerResponse> delete(ServerRequest request) {
  String id = request.pathVariable("id");
  return personManager
    .findById(id)
    .flatMap(u -> noContent().build(userManager.deleteUser(u)))
    // User is deleted
    // How to delete UserUsername 
    // also delete UserEmail
}
```

Comment: why are you duplicating data in the database?

Comment: Data duplication is necessary for a distributed database like Cassandra. Disks are cheaper nowadays. To improved Cassandra reads we need to duplicate the data so that we can ensure the availability of data in case of some failures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map user-username and user-email like below:

```
Create Table user (
  username text,
  userid bigint,
  password text,
  name text,
  email text,
  phone text,
  birthday text,
  biography text,
  PRIMARY KEY (username)
)

Create Table userUsername (
  username text,
  userid bigint,
  usernameid bigint,
  password text,
  name text,
  email text,
  phone text,
  birthday text,
  biography text,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid, usernameid)
)

Create Table userEmail (
  email text,
  emailid bigint,
  username text,
  userid bigint,
  password text,
  name text,
  phone text,
  birthday text,
  biography text,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid, emailid)
)
```

Comment: I think my model is right, with yours i can't solve my needs by finding a user based on their UserID,  Username and Email.